# HIShapeCreateDifference equivalent in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos

I tried searching but couldn't find a function which can create a shape by calculating difference of two NSBezier Paths or two CGPaths. Is there a function that can establish this in cocoa ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean a little? Finding the path that is the overlap between 2 paths? Or taking a path and cutting away another path from it?

Comment: @mike : It is the path obtained after cutting another path from it. For example, to form a ring using two concentric circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[Winding Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Paths/Paths.html)" with NSBezierPath. You'll make a compound path by appending your two source paths to it. The resulting shape will depend upon the winding rule you set.

Answer (score 0):

Finally did it by creating a bigger tracking area to enclose the whole shape and then tracking mouse moved events inside this tracking area.